# NullPointerException error in AbstractStateMachine.acceptEvent method

Tags: spring-statemachine

Below is my one class project, which is using spring-statemachine-core-1.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar, which implements a simple transition from one state to another. It's coughing up null pointer exception on **currentState** in **AbstractStateMachine.acceptEvent** method. Appreciate help/thoughts.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.acceptEvent(AbstractStateMachine.java:591)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineBuilder;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineBuilder.Builder;

public class Processor {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

        builder.configureStates()
            .withStates()
                .initial("INIT").end("END")
                .states(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("INIT","MIDDLE","END"))); 

        builder.configureTransitions()
        .withExternal()
        .source("INIT").target("MIDDLE").event("START")
        .and()
        .withExternal()
        .source("MIDDLE").target("END");

        builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().autoStartup(true);

        StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine = builder.build();
        stateMachine.start();               
        stateMachine.sendEvent("START");
        stateMachine.stop();

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes with manual builder machine doesn't get a default `taskExecutor`. It's already fixed in master and 1.0.x branch but we haven't released 1.0.3 yet. Workaround is to set it manually:

```
builder
    .configureConfiguration()
        .withConfiguration()
            .taskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor())
            .autoStartup(true);
```